# how to use the range function with _score value in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch to search and filter the data. Currently, I am getting all relevant search response when trying to query.For Example- When I try to get City:New York, I am getting all the values with word "New" and "York" whereas I want to get those data with "city:New york".

Therefore, I think _score value can be helpful for this scenario so I am trying to get the value of _score which is  greater or equals 20 using the range function.

This is the way I tried in kibana but it didn't worked. 
Thank you in advance !!

```
POST /employee/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {"match": {"name": "John doe"}},
        {"match": {"city": "New York"}},
        {"match": {"school": "Oxford private school "}},
        {"match": {"address": "Victoria Avenue"}},
        {"range": {"_score" : { "gte" : 22 }}}
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think to make the query with `_score` would help in this case since as far as I know that `_score` was calculated by ES engine and therefore **no assurance** to have the exact value.

Thus, you could use full text search instead of terms search. And thus, no analyzers apply for this text field.

See also at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html